# Building PCB mountable inverter for an EL panel

Tags: pcb, inverter, light

To a circuit for a light installation I want to add an inverter for powering an EL panel. Ideally, the inverter can be mounted on a PCB.

- Input voltage: 5 V
- Output voltage: to power an EL panel at *maximum brightness*

For the [EL Panel - Green 10cm x 10cm](https://www.seeedstudio.com/EL-Panel-Green-10cm-x-10cm-p-1190.html) offered by seeed (just a random pick), recommended input is:

- 120 V
- 1500 Hz – 2000 Hz

I found [12 ICs on Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/short/30cw28) to drive EL inverter circuits with 5 V of input ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoPRh.png)). None of these, however, is able to output frequencies in the range of 1500 to 2000 Hz.

*These ICs don’t work for the intended purpose, right?*

*Are there other options, or should we better just use a fully assembled EL inverter?*

(The fully assembled EL inverters normally are not PCB mountable. The only PCB mountable inverter that we found, called [WE-50](https://www.conrad.de/de/el-inverter-5-vdc-schwarz-l-x-b-x-h-27-x-175-x-19-mm-conrad-components-we-50-184005.html), is unfortunately not very powerful, i.e. the brightness of the connected panel was quite low.)

Comment: I think you need to find an EL panel that has a comprehensive data sheet - the webpage does say it will operate from 50 Hz to 5000 Hz so what is the problem - I see at least one IC that will do the job.

Comment: @Andyaka It says “Optimum: 1500 Hz – 2000 Hz.” We are looking for maximum brightness, as the lights should be visible during daylight. I assume lower frequencies will not do the job as well.

Comment: How much better is "optimal" compared to "non-optimal" and, does "optimal" necessarily mean brighter (it could mean more efficient for instance). So, find a panel that has a comprehensive data sheet from a reputable supplier made by a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: @Andyaka To my knowledge, at least with EL wire, a higher frequency means a higher brightness. A too high frequency may have a negative impact on life time.

Comment: Notice the number of answers you have. Find an EL light with a data sheet.